# command to stitch two videos of vertically

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

I am trying to stitch two video vertically in which each video should take half of the screen i am using https://tanersener.github.io/mobile-ffmpeg/ as ffmpeg client, can anyone help me with the correct command

Answer (score 1):

You can stitch 2 videos with the `vstack` filter. I'm not familiar with mobile-ffmpeg but the ffmpeg command is:

(The `\` is not part of ffmpeg. It's only a line break for a shell to make the command more readable.)

```
ffmpeg -y -i "video_top.mp4" -i "video_bottom.mp4" -filter_complex "\
[0:v]scale=960:540,pad=1920:540:(ow-iw)/2:0,setsar=1[0v];\
[1:v]scale=960:540,pad=1920:540:(ow-iw)/2:0,setsar=1[1v];\
[0v][1v]vstack[v];\
[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[a]\
" -map '[v]' -map '[a]' \
"vertically_stiched_videos.mp4"
```

[image: vstack-filter]

This code is from [here](https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/ffmpeg/create_comparison_video/simplest_with_vstack_2_.html).

You can look at other examples for the `vstack` filter on this page: [ffmpeg examples](https://hhsprings.bitbucket.io/docs/programming/examples/ffmpeg/index.html)

(Simply search in your browser on this page for "*create comparison video for two videos*".)